# Fluentd (td-agent) fluent-plugin-filter-base64-decode v.0.2.0 - incorrect decoding

Tags: base64, fluentd

I am trying to decode a string by td-agent filter, as a result the end of the string looks like garbage.
base64 of bash decoded it fine.
Maybe someone can help
td-agent running on Centos7 latest kernel. fluentd-1.9.2

String:

```
{"message":"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 b3JlZj1odHRwcyUzQSUyRiUyRnd3dy5hdWRpYmxlLmNvbSUyRmVwJTJGZnJlZXRyaWFsJTNGc291cmNlX2NvZGUlM0RXQVBHQjEzNzEyMDcxODAwNEY/CTE="}
```

Comment: The problematic string is:

Comment: What is *incorrect* decoding? What result did you expect and what did you actually get. Base64 is pretty straight forward and when I try [online](https://www.base64decode.org/) I also see some non-prinatable stuff on the end, but off course I don't know what to expect.